# error: expression must have a constant value

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, constants

I need some help to find how to resolve this error.

```
typedef struct {
    const char *iName;
    const char *iComment;
} T_Entry;

const T_Entry Menu_PowerSupply = { "PWRS", "Power supply"};

static const T_Entry G_Commands[] = {
    { "MEM", "Memory"},
    {Menu_PowerSupply.iName,Menu_PowerSupply.iComment},
    { "SYS", "System"}
};
```

I got the error : **expression must have a constant value**
How can I solve this ?

For me at link time is known and at a fixed address with a fixed value : Am I wrong

---

My purpose is to put  the following code into a library

```
const T_Entry Menu_PowerSupply = { "PWRS", "Power supply"};
```

The following not work either

```
static const T_Entry G_Commands[] = {
    { "MEM", "Memory"},
    Menu_PowerSupply,
    { "SYS", "System"}
};
```

If someone could help me to understand this ***non const*** values ...

Answer (score 5):

The error is because the initializer for global variables must be constant expression, but even though `Menu_PowerSupply` is defined as `const`, it's not a constant expression.

This is similar to:

```
const int n = 42;
int arr[n];
```

doesn't compile in C89 because `n` is not a constant expression. (it does compile in C99 only because C99 supports VLA)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the **addresses** of *global* and/or *static* variables **are** considered compile time constants.  So if you make `G_Commands` an array-of-pointers, then you can initialize the array as shown below

```
typedef struct
{
    const char *iName;
    const char *iComment;
}
    T_Entry;

const T_Entry EntryMemory      = { "MEM" , "Memory"       };
const T_Entry EntryPowerSupply = { "PWRS", "Power supply" };
const T_Entry EntrySystem      = { "SYS" , "System"       };

static const T_Entry *G_Commands[] =
{
    &EntryMemory,
    &EntryPowerSupply,
    &EntrySystem,
    NULL
};

static const T_Entry *G_Menus[] =
{
    &EntryPowerSupply,
    NULL
};

int main( void )
{
    const T_Entry **entry, *command, *menu;

    printf( "Commands:\n" );
    for ( entry = G_Commands; *entry != NULL; entry++ )
    {
        command = *entry;
        printf( "   %-4s %s\n", command->iName, command->iComment );
    }

    printf( "\nMenus:\n" );
    for ( entry = G_Menus; *entry != NULL; entry++ )
    {
        menu = *entry;
        printf( "   %-4s %s\n", menu->iName, menu->iComment );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately constant variables cannot be used in constant expressions. They are considered to be variables that cannot change, but not constants that can be determined at compile time.

Workaround:

```
#define MENU_PWRSPLY_NAME    "PWRS"
#define MENU_PWRSPLY_COMMENT "Power supply"

const T_Entry Menu_PowerSupply = { MENU_PWRSPLY_NAME, MENU_PWRSPLY_COMMENT };

static const T_Entry G_Commands[] = {
    { "MEM", "Memory"},
    { MENU_PWRSPLY_NAME, MENU_PWRSPLY_COMMENT },
    { "SYS", "System"}
};
```

Comment: Doesn't `Menu_PowerSupply` become redundant here ?! Since `MENU_PWRSPLY_NAME` & `MENU_PWRSPLY_COMMENT` are _basically_ substituted.

Comment: @SaurabhMeshram It depends on whether `Menu_PowerSupply` is used elsewhere or not.