# Error in string array initializer: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, compile-time-constant

I need to define some strings and an array initialized with those strings available to use by different pieces of the software. I thought in defining them in a header file like this:

```c
//.h file
const char *serviceStateKindNormal = "Normal";
const char *serviceStateKindUnmanned = "Unmanned";
const char *serviceStateKindScheduledMaintenanceDown = "ScheduledMaintenance (down)";
const char *serviceStateKindScheduledMaintenanceAvailable = "ScheduledMaintenance (available)";
const char *serviceStateKindMajorIncidentInProgress = "MajorIncidentInProgress";
const char *serviceStateKindPartialService = "PartialService";
const char *serviceStateKindOverloaded = "Overloaded";
const char *serviceStateKindGoingDown = "GoingDown";
const char *serviceStateKindDown = "Down";

const char *serviceStateKind[9] = {
    serviceStateKindNormal,
    serviceStateKindUnmanned,
    serviceStateKindScheduledMaintenanceDown,
    serviceStateKindScheduledMaintenanceAvailable,
    serviceStateKindMajorIncidentInProgress,
    serviceStateKindPartialService,
    serviceStateKindOverloaded,
    serviceStateKindGoingDown,
    serviceStateKindDown
};
```

but the compiler shows

```
error: initializer element is not constant
     serviceStateKindNormal
```

what exactly is the problem here and what choices do I have to define my variables?

Comment: Why not just put literals directly to the array initializer?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25542109/694733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C language constant refers to literal constants, like (`3.14`, `2.718`, etc).
Const-qualified objects (of any type) are not constants in C language terminology.

For creating constants in C language terminology use `#define` directive, for example:

`#define ServiceStateKindNormal "Normal"`

etc.

Comment: I mean keyword `const` in C isn't equivalent to `constant` in C++ or other languages. Word constant is used for numerical and symbols literals.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you put in an intialized of a variable that is declared at file scope must be a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) or a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), from [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization). There is a list what is a constant expression and variable value is not among them. So:

```
 // there is an array of char[2]{'a',\0'} somewhere in the memory
 // we store the pointer value to that array inside the variable a
 static const char *a = "a";
 // now we want to statically initialize variable b with the same value
 static const char *b = a;
```

will not work, because `b` is initialized with the pointer `a` *value*, which is not a constant expression. You need a constant expression when initializing a variable with static storage duration.

What can you do? The following:

1. The good way: Why do you store the pointers to the string literals `"Normal"`? Why not store the data itself inside the array? Happily, variable address is a constant expression, so we can use it in initialization! Note that (almost) all use cases and semantics stay the same, except for some corner usage like `sizeof(serviceStateKindNormal)` operator results.

   ```
   const char serviceStateKindNormal[] = "Normal";
   const char serviceStateKindUnmanned[] = "Unmanned";

   const char *serviceStateKind[] = {
       serviceStateKindNormal,
       serviceStateKindUnmanned,
   };
   ```
2. A strange way: store the pointers to the pointers to strings inside the array. As variable addresses are constant expressions, this will work. Note that makes the `serviceStateKind` a three star variable. You need to double dereference the array on usage. The `serviceStateKind` is an array of pointers of pointers to strings. Note that it is very confusing on how to use such array, so I suggest you go with a structure then.

   ```
   const char *serviceStateKindNormal = "Normal";
   const char *serviceStateKindUnmanned = "Unmanned";

   const char **serviceStateKind[] = {
       &serviceStateKindNormal,
       &serviceStateKindUnmanned,
   };

   int main() {
       // question which one is correct?
       printf("%s\n", *serviceStateKind[1]);
       printf("%s\n", (*serviceStateKind)[1]);
       printf("%s\n", serviceStateKind[0][1]);
   }
   ```

but as i don't think of myself as a three star programmer, I would try to make it at least to two stars:

```
    const char *serviceStateKindNormal = "Normal";
    const char *serviceStateKindUnmanned = "Unmanned";

    struct {
        // points to a string
        const char **pnt;
    // an array of pointers to string
    } serviceStateKind[] = {
        &serviceStateKindNormal,
        &serviceStateKindUnmanned,
    };

    int main() {
        // more verbose
        printf("%s\n", *serviceStateKind[0].pnt);
    }
```

2. The old fashioned way - macros. Don't do it. And what is bad about it, you can abuse preprocessor concatenation of string literals, to concatenate them together.

   ```
   #define serviceStateKindNormal  "Normal"
   #define serviceStateKindUnmanned  "Unmanned"

   const char *serviceStateKind[] = {
       serviceStateKindNormal,
       serviceStateKindUnmanned,
   };

   int main() { 
      # magic
      printf(serviceStateKindNormal " " serviceStateKindUnmanned "\n");
   }
   ```

> I thought in defining them in a header file like this:

If you are defining the variables in a header file, you want to mark them with `static`, so that you will not get duplicate symbol errors on linking with different `.c` files that use that `.h` file. Also it's nice to mark the variable as `const` as a hint to other programmers that they are somewhat not changable.

Comment: Could you explain why `const char serviceStateKindNormal[] = "Normal";` is preferred over `char const * const serviceStateKindNormal = "Normal";` ? (which I provided in my answer which just collected a bunch of downvotes)

Comment: Hm, because it makes no sense, unless you really need a pointer to an array. I wouldn't name it as "preferred", it's different memory layout. In the first case you have a variable that in itself is an array and stores the 7 characters length string. In the second case you have a pointer to an array. I called it "the good way (TM)" here because I think it is the most readable and reliable way of doing the thing. You collected downvotes, because declaring the variable as `const` doesn't allow initializing other variable with it's value, so it does not solve the problem.

Comment: So you're saying `char const * const a = "a"; const char * b = a;` should not compile? Even when compiled with `-std=c90 -pedantic -Wall` both clang and gcc compile without warning. https://ideone.com/TYhjX9

Comment: @Lanting: Are you sure the ideone uses a C compiler and not a C++ compiler? My gcc gives "*error: initializer element is not constant*" for this "*`char const * const a = "a"; const char * b = a;`*"

Comment: @Lanting So, for future readers, initializing an element with a `const` qualified variable is a compiler extension. I was curious by your comment, so I [asked about it here onstackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135942/why-initializer-element-is-not-a-constant-is-not-working-anymore).