# Can const variable be available at compile time?

Tags: c

I have following code:

```c
const char *login_msg_type = "A";
struct handler handlers[] = {
    {"0", res_heartbeat},
    {login_msg_type, res_login},
};
```

Compiler throws an error stating that "initializer element is not constant". Well, I know I can `#define` that value but I want the variable to have a type. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try `const char * const`?

Comment: I did not knew that is possible to state `const` twice. Amazing, thank you. It is required to stick to this order `const char * const`? I tried `const const char *` and it did not worked.

Comment: `const char *` is a variable pointer to a const char, `char * const` is a const pointer to a variable char, `const char * const` is a const pointer to a const char.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135942/why-initializer-element-is-not-a-constant-is-not-working-anymore , the second example is very similar. The question is "*Can* const variable be available at compile time?". They "can", but it's not part of the language, not all compilers (versions) support it, and it's a compiler extension.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733418/yunnosch), [@arkku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204883/arkku) stated in the comments section, the answer is

```
const char * const login_msg_type = "A";
```

> const char * is a variable pointer to a const char, char * const is a const pointer to a variable char, const char * const is a const pointer to a const char.

Comment: What does your answer adds to the discussion? The answer should contain an explanation. You just point on the other person's comment, that, explained it better.

Comment: It adds an answer. Many people do not read comments, so I decided to write one. And I think the answer should resolve the problem or answer the question, first of all.