# Compiling in GCC but not in Clang: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"

Tags: gcc, static, constants, compile-time-constant

I'm having this error (in the title) when I use the compiler clang-15 (15.0.7). Below is a minimum reproducible code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUF_SIZE    255
#define ID_SIZE (sizeof(uint32_t))
#define F_SIZE      (sizeof(uint8_t))
#define TS_SIZE        (sizeof(uint64_t))
#define CRC_SIZE       (sizeof(uint16_t))
#define PL_LEN      (16)
#define MSG_SIZE       (ID_SIZE + PL_LEN + F_SIZE)
#define RST_FS         (0U)


typedef union {
    struct {
        uint32_t id;                  
        uint8_t  pl[PL_LEN];          
        uint8_t  fs;                           
    } __attribute__((packed));
    uint8_t msg_buf[MSG_SIZE];
} TM;

typedef union {
    struct {
        uint8_t  strt;
        TM msg;
        uint16_t crc;
        uint8_t  end;
    } __attribute__((packed));
    uint8_t msg_buf[BUF_SIZE];
} TM_BUF;


/* LOCAL CONSTANTS */
static const TM RST_MSG = {
    .id = 0x0000U,   
    .pl = {0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U,0U},
    .fs = RST_FS,
};

static const TM_BUF RST_BUF = {
    .strt= 0U,
    .msg = RST_MSG,
    .crc = 0U,
    .end = 0U,
};

int main (void){

    printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I have read in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135942/why-initializer-element-is-not-a-constant-is-not-working-anymore) that this has something to do with compiler conflict and clearly looks like it. What's the best workaround here?

The code above compiles using GCC 9.4.0 compiler in Ubuntu.